# How to change this javascript only to use only 1 link

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript:- when we click on the 'home' link it shows home stuff,then when we click the 'about' link it shows the about related things. How to make this only to have one button and that 1 button should be able to change links on clicks. Here is the code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > function show(page) {
var html = "";
switch (page) {
    case "home":
        html = 'All the stuff of the page';
        break;
    case "about":
        html = 'All the stuff of the pahe';
        break;
    case "contact":
        html = "This is the contact page<br />...";
        break;
}
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

**[A working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/z2UCX)**

Comment: You want the button to cycle through the pages automatically? Otherwise, how would the button ever know that you're on "about" and want to go view "home"?

Comment: What would the button look like? I can't picture this.

Comment: I would like to add an 'arrow' image to the button or an image link. Yes cycle through the div tags. This uses 4 different link to go to 4 divs. When we go to the 2nd DIV, 2nd dive's button should take it to the 3rd DIV,and that button to the 4th DIV

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions are good, but switch statements, IMO, are overused, confusing and lead to many unnecessary bugs.  Here's a shorter alternative using an object instead.

```
function show(page) {
    var content = {
        home : 'All the stuff of the page<br />...',
        about : 'All the stuff about the page<br />...',
        contact : 'This is the contact page<br />...'
    }

    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = content[page];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You had a ton of typos and sytax errors in the fiddle.

Here's a fixed version - if that's what you wanted.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">This is the homepage
    <br />...</div>
<a href="#" title="Home" onclick="show('home');return false">Home</a>

<a href="#" title="About" onclick="show('about');return false">About</a>

<a href="#" title="Contact" onclick="show('contact');return false">Contact</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function show(page) {
    var html = "";
    switch (page) {
        case "home":
            html = 'All the stuff of the page  ';
            break;
        case "about":
            html = 'All the stuff of the pahe';
            break;
        case "contact":
            html = "This is the contact page<br />...";
            break;
    }

    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
}
```

**[Link to working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2UCX/5/)**

You were missing `break` and had some other weird stuff there.

Comment: Icarus all you changed is the settings of the fiddle. the code is the same.

Comment: yes, I know. But your fiddle wasn't working because the settings where incorrect.

Comment: FYI I up voted your answer even before you corrected your fiddle. If I down vote something I usually say so and explain why, unless there are already commments from someone else explaining what's wrong...

Comment: It was meant in general, to the downvoter. I would've used a @ tag were it at you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10225843)

Comment: @JohnSlegers Do you really come to two years old answer just to give a downvote? what's wrong with you

Comment: @MightyPork : I can assure you that I don't downvote answers just for being link only answer. I'm not an asshole.  I merely reviewed the answer after (one or more) other people had flagged it, but I didn't downvote it.

Answer (score -2):

Add a parameter when calling the function, the `event` parameter, which will ensure that the default behavior of the `AnchorDOMElement` is not triggered by calling `event.preventDefault();`.

The JavaScript code must be put in between `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags within your `<head>` HTML tag ***OR*** within your `<body>` tag, at the beginning or the end of it.

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">This is the homepage<br />...</div>
<a href="#" title="Home" onclick="show(event,'home');">Home</a>
<a href="#" title="About" onclick="show(event,'about');">About</a>
<a href="#" title="Contact" onclick="show(event,'contact');">Contact</a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function show(event, page) {
    /* This prevents the regular anchor behaviors */
    event.preventDefault();
    var html = "";
    switch (page) {
        case "home":
            html = 'All the stuff of the page  ';
            break;
        case "about":
            /* You forgot to close the ' properly here */
            html = 'All the stuff about the page';
            break;
        case "contact":
            html = "This is the contact  page<br/>...";
            break;
    }
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
}
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/z2UCX/3/)

Comment: scripts don't have to go into the head.  They merely need to be available before the code that uses them is triggered.  It's a common performance improvement to add them at the bottom of the html stream rather than in the head, so they don't block rendering.

Comment: @RayWadkins Does this invalidate my whole answer? I don't think the user really cares about performance, otherwise his code would be done differently. My answer is still valid concerning OP's question. To suit your needs, I added an **or** to my sentence. I still highly doubt this script would've blocked the page load, even on a PC running a P133 cpu.